# a regex for cleaning quotes between quotes

Tags: regex, shortcode

I'm trying write a regex that clears double quotes inside double quotes of a shortcode attribute.

I wrote this regex

```
\="(.*?)\"
```

and it matches the string between quotes http://regex101.com/r/jW0uC4

But when I have attribute value that also contains double quotes it fails http://regex101.com/r/pL9bI0

So, how can i improve the regex as it will catch the string only between =" and last "

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think `title="Title with "quotes" and "html tags <br />""` is valid. Those quotes should be escaped like `title="Title with \"quotes\" and \"html tags <br />\""`. And in that case you could use a lookbehind in the regex or something similar.

Comment: @GergoErdosi yes i know they're not valid. I'm just trying to fix it if user use it wrong. It is very common mistake.

Comment: You MUST use `&quot;` to escape any quotation marks within HTML attribute values. Using the quotation mark itself is a protocol violation. And there is no other acceptable way to escape them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex matches the sample text you provided:

```
/="(.*?)"(?=\s*(?:[a-z]+=|]))/
```

Explanation:

```
  ="                       '="'
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
  )                        end of \1
  "                        '"'
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
      [a-z]+                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (1 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
      =                        '='
     |                        OR
      ]                        ']'
    )                        end of grouping
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

But user errors are hard to fix and this regex may not work in all cases (for example if text contains an `=` character). You should make sure user input is escaped properly.